# What's wrong with this result_of usage?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

```
auto lambda = [](){ return 7; };
std::result_of<decltype(lambda)()>::type val = lambda(); //  'val' : illegal use of type 'void'
```

I get the error: `'val' : illegal use of type 'void'`. Why would the type resolve as void?

I may be mistaken about what `result_of` gets me. I just want the return value from anything I can pass a `std::function`.

Comment: Update your compiler: http://liveworkspace.org/code/7f4d53e90a0865c8056106fd98f8c309

Comment: no error for me with gcc 4.7.0 ...

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `auto val = lambda()`?  From the looks of it, it might be your compiler not quite supporting that feature completely yet.

Comment: this is just a small example demonstrating my issue. Actually I'm using this for a return value, and a template argument instead of `lambda`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your compiler fails to compile that, then don't use `std::result_of`:

```
decltype(lambda()) val = lambda();
```

That is exactly the same, and it should(well, could) work in VC2010.

You could also use `auto`,  though I don't think this is what you want:

```
auto val = lambda();
```

**Edit**: Since you're using this in the return value of a function, then the `decltype` solution shown above works fine:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

template<class Functor>
auto foo(const Functor &f) -> decltype(f()) {
    return f();
}

int main() {
    auto lambda = [](){ return 7; };
    auto val = foo(lambda);
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << std::is_same<decltype(val), int>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Demo [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/09c6179fd73f108e8bc5334b514d0a6a).

Comment: whats the difference between auto and the long way?

Comment: @Gir the type of `val` will be the same, so there's no actual difference. But maybe OP is trying to avoid `auto` for some reason(maybe he'll use that type as a template argument to a function).

Comment: @Gir Using `auto` results in taking a copy of the result. Using `decltype` matches the type exactly, so for instance references are preserved.